# Is Response Action free to use in Power Automate?

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, powerapp, licensing, power-automate

In Power Automate we have the Response Action which has the Premium label with it.

[image]

Even though it is premium action, I am able to use it with the user who has a **Power Automate Free** license.

**My user does not have any P1 or P2 license.**

How is this possible? Is it something free trial?

Can someone please provide official details links on this topic?

**Note: I am using this action to return data from SharePoint to Power Apps.**

Answer (score 0):

**Response** action in Power Automate is Premium action and it is not free to use.

The user must be using a **free trial** for this.

Comment: How can I verify that free trial is started?

Comment: On the O365 the Admin Portal, User does not have any trial license assigned.